# Call C# method with parameter from JS xamarin

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin, android-jsinterface

I tried to call C# method from JS with arguments, but I've got an error.

I'm using Xamarin Android (not Xamarin.Forms)

C# Code:

```
[JavascriptInterface]
[Export("test")]
public Java.Lang.String Test(Java.Lang.String hello)
{
    return hello;
}
```

JS Code:

```
var foo = GameBridge.test('foo');
```

Error:`System.InvalidOperationException: Specified managed method 'Test' was not found. Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;`

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x82F.png)

Comment: I made a basic demo but didn't reproduced your problem, Could you please try follow the [Call C# from JavaScript](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/). If the error persists, could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the return type of the c# method. It works well with return type as 'void'. 
Below code working to me.

```
[JavascriptInterface]
[Export("test")]
public void Test(string hello)
{
    //to do work
}
```

I am also looking for to handle return types in Export/JavascriptInterface.